# Is this mold or not?

Tags: doors, mold, patio

[image]

Mold or dirt? Leak for 6 months saturating this area.

Comment: Does it have spores?  Spores would give a sort of dust.  // I'm not sure, but I think I see some efflorescence on the metal along the sides. // If you want to play it safe, you could spray a 50% vinegar solution on the whole area to kill any mold that might be there, before starting your cleaning.  Also, do you have a hygrometer to measure the humidity?  Mold is more likely to grow well in higher humidity.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell from the photo, it looks more like rust than mould. I'd wash off the loose dirt first to be sure though.

Comment: I agree it looks more like dirt.